# Is the boolean constant True a Horn formula?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The wikipedia definition of Horn formulas state that they are a conjunction of Horn clauses. So, by that logic, would it not be true that the empty conjunction, equal to the boolean constant True, is a Horn formula? Strangely though no proofs regarding Horn formulas seem to consider that case, and instead only consider cases where the formula has a non-empty number of clauses...

Comment: Good question. I'd think so, but let's see what the experts say.

Comment: Yes; see [Horn clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause): "a unit clause without variables is a fact"

Comment: But is that not the empty clause, not the empty conjunction of clauses?

Comment: Yes, True is a Horn formula. Can you give a reference to a proof that doesn't handle that case? Is it possible that the proofs you're reading are implicitly handling that case, by arguing that something is true for each Horn clause, in which case the argument works vacuously in the case when there are no clauses?

Comment: If you have problems about specific proofs, then tell us what those proofs are. Making broad statements about proofs in general makes you question impossible to answer.